# Celery periodic tasks does not execute

Tags: python-2.7, celery, cloud9-ide

I am using cloud 9 online IDE for python dev.
Here's my code:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab 
from datetime import timedelta

RESULT_URL = 'mongodb://********' 
BROKER_URL = 'redis://*********'

app = Celery('tasks', backend=RESULT_URL,broker=BROKER_URL)
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'

 CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'add-every-30-seconds': {
    'task': 'tasks.add',
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
    'args': (16, 16)
},
}

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    print x+y
    return x + y
```

And I am starting it out with the command:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info --beat
```

Celery starts OK,but stops all activity there.Manually invoked tasks work fine.
Here's the console log:

```
[2015-04-16 07:53:30,954: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
[2015-04-16 07:53:32,696: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://*******
[2015-04-16 07:53:34,722: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2015-04-16 07:53:37,685: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2015-04-16 07:53:40,343: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@*****-demo-project-563148 ready.
```

I am using RedisLabs free-version as  the Broker and a self hosted mongo as the backend storage. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: Not yet.As a workaround I used APScheduler to kick off the tasks.

Comment: I got it to work. Did you start celery beat service separately?

Comment: I started celery with the "--beat" option.According to the [docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) this should start the beat service along with celery.

Comment: How did you use APScheduler to kick off the task?

Comment: @user805981 I used the APscheduler's scheduled_job decorator to specify the function which was to be invoked periodically.The body of this function invoked the celery task by explicitly calling it.[This](http://pastebin.com/Reb3Pp7P) shows my code structure.